# Subquery not returning expected results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, subquery

This is the query I have written to get the plans chosen by an user. But this is returning the records in *usersubscription* table even if the user is not subscribed (if there is no records in the table corresponding to the user).

```
$userid=$_POST['userid'];
$videoid=$_POST['videoid'];
$subscribedquery=$this->db->query("select id from usersubscription where plan_id IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT plan_id FROM subscribed_videos sv where sv.videoid = $videoid)
        OR id IN (SELECT DISTINCT assosiated_plan_id 
        FROM subscription_groups sg
        JOIN subscribed_videos sv ON sv.plan_id = sg.plan_id
        WHERE sv.videoid = $videoid) and user_id=$userid");
```

Below I am sharing the structure of all tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subscribed_videos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `plan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `videoid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;

INSERT INTO `subscribed_videos` (`id`, `plan_id`, `videoid`) VALUES
(7, 2, 1),
(8, 2, 2),
(14, 1, 3),
(15, 1, 4),
(16, 1, 5),
(17, 1, 21),
(18, 1, 28),
(19, 1, 2),
(20, 3, 4),
(21, 3, 6),
(24, 5, 25),
(25, 6, 5);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subscription_groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `plan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `assosiated_plan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added_on` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


INSERT INTO `subscription_groups` (`id`, `plan_id`, `assosiated_plan_id`, `added_on`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 0),
(2, 2, 2, 0),
(3, 3, 3, 0),
(4, 4, 1, 0),
(5, 4, 2, 0),
(6, 4, 3, 0),
(12, 5, 5, 0),
(13, 5, 1, 0),
(14, 5, 2, 0),
(15, 6, 1, 0);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subscription_plans` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `plan` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `days_limit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added_on` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);



INSERT INTO `subscription_plans` (`id`, `plan`, `days_limit`, `added_on`, `status`, `rate`) VALUES
(1, 'PlanA', 15, 1398249706, 1, 150.00),
(2, 'PlanB', 15, 1398249679, 1, 100.00),
(3, 'PlanC', 15, 1398249747, 1, 100.00),
(4, 'PlanD', 10, 1398249771, 1, 500.00),
(5, 'PlanE', 15, 1398250104, 1, 200.00),
(6, 'Plan R1', 20, 1398250104, 1, 200.00);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usersubscription` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `plan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subscribed_on` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);



INSERT INTO `usersubscription` (`id`, `user_id`, `plan_id`, `subscribed_on`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1399091458);
```

Content:

```
SELECT * FROM subscribed_videos; 
+----+---------+---------+
| id | plan_id | videoid |
+----+---------+---------+
|  7 |       2 |       1 |
|  8 |       2 |       2 |
| 14 |       1 |       3 |
| 15 |       1 |       4 |
| 16 |       1 |       5 |
| 17 |       1 |      21 |
| 18 |       1 |      28 |
| 19 |       1 |       2 |
| 20 |       3 |       4 |
| 21 |       3 |       6 |
| 24 |       5 |      25 |
| 25 |       6 |       5 |
+----+---------+---------+

SELECT * FROM subscription_groups; 
+----+---------+--------------------+----------+
| id | plan_id | assosiated_plan_id | added_on |
+----+---------+--------------------+----------+
|  1 |       1 |                  1 |        0 |
|  2 |       2 |                  2 |        0 |
|  3 |       3 |                  3 |        0 |
|  4 |       4 |                  1 |        0 |
|  5 |       4 |                  2 |        0 |
|  6 |       4 |                  3 |        0 |
| 12 |       5 |                  5 |        0 |
| 13 |       5 |                  1 |        0 |
| 14 |       5 |                  2 |        0 |
| 15 |       6 |                  1 |        0 |
+----+---------+--------------------+----------+

SELECT * FROM subscription_plans;
+----+---------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| id | plan    | days_limit | added_on   | status | rate   |
+----+---------+------------+------------+--------+--------+
|  1 | PlanA   |         15 | 1398249706 |      1 | 150.00 |
|  2 | PlanB   |         15 | 1398249679 |      1 | 100.00 |
|  3 | PlanC   |         15 | 1398249747 |      1 | 100.00 |
|  4 | PlanD   |         10 | 1398249771 |      1 | 500.00 |
|  5 | PlanE   |         15 | 1398250104 |      1 | 200.00 |
|  6 | Plan R1 |         20 | 1398250104 |      1 | 200.00 |
+----+---------+------------+------------+--------+--------+

 SELECT * FROM usersubscription
+----+---------+---------+---------------+
| id | user_id | plan_id | subscribed_on |
+----+---------+---------+---------------+
|  1 |       1 |       1 |    1399091458 |
+----+---------+---------+---------------+
```

Fiddle of same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90b2e/1

I expect the result to be like this if the user is already subscribed to a plan of the selected video otherwise the query should return empty records:

```
id
---
1
```

Also how can I return the records only if the plan is not expired for the user using the query itself. ie, when an user purchases a plan, it will be entered in the *usersubscription* table. The *subscribed_on* field will contain the php unix `time()` in which it is purchased. So I would like to get only the plans corresponding to a user and a video, which is not expired, in this query. The expiry days is stored as days in *days_limit* field of *subscription_plans* table (eg: 15).

Can anyone help me to find an appropriate solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it would be good if you add the tables and data in http://sqlfiddle.com along with the expected result to your question.

Comment: Plz check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90b2e/1

Comment: @Jenz can you add the desired output you need to return from your query

Comment: @Khalid I'l update my question here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you should try this using joins

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.id ,
FROM_UNIXTIME(p.`added_on`),
DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(s.`subscribed_on`), INTERVAL p.`days_limit` DAY) `expiry_date`
FROM usersubscription s
LEFT JOIN subscribed_videos v ON (s.plan_id = v.plan_id)
LEFT JOIN subscription_groups g ON(s.id = assosiated_plan_id )
LEFT JOIN subscribed_videos sv ON sv.plan_id = g.plan_id
LEFT JOIN `subscription_plans` p ON (p.id = s.plan_id)
WHERE s.user_id=1 AND  sv.videoid = 5
AND  v.videoid = 5
AND  DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(s.`subscribed_on`), INTERVAL p.`days_limit` DAY) > CURRENT_DATE()
```

In above query i have an additional join `subscription_plans` to check your expiry date condition, also note you are using post variables directly in query i.e `$userid=$_POST['userid'];$videoid=$_POST['videoid'];` which is not safe and when you are using codeigniter then you should use active record library to build your query which will take of all escaping at its own end

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90b2e/20)

Here is the active record version of above query

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('s.id')
    ->distinct()
    ->from('usersubscription s')
    ->join('subscribed_videos v ','s.plan_id = v.plan_id','LEFT')
    ->join('subscription_groups g ','s.id = assosiated_plan_id','LEFT')
    ->join('subscribed_videos sv','sv.plan_id = g.plan_id','LEFT')
    ->join('`subscription_plans` p','p.id = s.plan_id','LEFT')
    ->where('s.user_id',$userid)
    ->where('sv.videoid',$videoid)
    ->where('v.videoid',$videoid)
    ->where('DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(s.`subscribed_on`), INTERVAL p.`days_limit` DAY) > CURRENT_DATE()',null,FALSE)
    ->get();
```

Comment: But this is returning records even if I subscribed one month before. The query should return records only if I have subscribed to a plan for the selected video and which is not expired (If I subscribe to a video which have day limit of 15 days, I should not be able to get the result when I try after 15 days from date of subscription).

Comment: @Jenz how it is possible read the last where clause it is simply checking if `added_on + days_limit` is greater than today's date then return which means its not expired right ,now can you show the sample data on which you are trying ?

Comment: I added `1380652200` (that corresponds to the date 01 Oct 2013) as the `subscribed_on` in `usersubscription` table corresponding to plan id 1 which has day limit of 15 days. But yet it is returning records.

Comment: @Jenz see my updated query i got wrong column in checking the expiry date i should have used `subscribed_on` instead of `added_on` see if it works

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking at ?

```
select 
id 
from 
usersubscription 
where 
(
  plan_id 
    IN 
    (
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT plan_id 
        FROM 
        subscribed_videos sv where sv.videoid = 5
      )
    )
   OR id IN 
  (
       SELECT DISTINCT assosiated_plan_id AS plan_id
       FROM subscription_groups sg
       JOIN subscribed_videos sv ON sv.plan_id = sg.plan_id
       WHERE sv.videoid = 5
   )
) 

and user_id=1;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90b2e/11)

Comment: @Abhik..Thanks a lot..It is working..How can I find only the plans which are not expired. I have explained it in my question. Can you help me to get an idea of how to implement it in this query?

Comment: You can do as http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90b2e/19 or as suggested by @Khalid i.e. using JOIN instead of subquery.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty sorry buddy i snatched your accepted answer but you already have my upvote on this answer

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I always advocate better answer and urs one is far better than me, using joins make query better in terms of readability and performance than sub queries. And better answer always helps others :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing query to:

```
$subscribedquery=$this->db->query("select id from usersubscription where plan_id IN 
    ((SELECT DISTINCT plan_id FROM subscribed_videos sv where sv.videoid = $videoid)
    OR id IN (SELECT DISTINCT assosiated_plan_id 
    FROM subscription_groups sg
    JOIN subscribed_videos sv ON sv.plan_id = sg.plan_id
    WHERE sv.videoid = $videoid)) and user_id=$userid");
```

I added brackets to change operator precedence

Comment: @Marcin...Getting error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`